# What is the formula for calculating combinations that have different permutations?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Hopefully the title of this question isn't the incorrect way to phrase the problem I'm having. If so let me know and I'll update it.

I have three items (A, B and C) and each item has three unique values (1, 2 and 3) they can hold.

How can I calculate all the various combinations? Where A, B, C might not always appear together at once.

Below is a list of 36 combinations (hopefully I've not missed any)...

```
A=1
A=2
A=3
B=1
B=2
B=3
C=1
C=2
C=3
A=1, B=1
A=1, B=2
A=1, B=3
A=2, B=1
A=2, B=2
A=2, B=3
A=1, C=1
A=1, C=2
A=1, C=3
A=2, C=1
A=2, C=2
A=2, C=3
B=1, C=1
B=1, C=2
B=1, C=3
B=2, C=1
B=2, C=2
B=2, C=3
A=1, B=1, C=1
A=2, B=2, C=2
A=3, B=3, C=3
A=2, B=1, C=1
A=3, B=1, C=1
A=1, B=2, C=1
A=1, B=3, C=1
A=1, B=1, C=2
A=1, B=1, C=3
```

### UPDATE/ADDITIONAL QUESTION

What would the formula look like if there were a larger number of values assigned to `A`, `B` and `C`. For A might hold numbers from 1-4, where as B might hold numbers 1-10, and C might hold numbers 1-2.

Comment: What is the rule for the range of values that the variables can have? I see for example. $A=1, B=1$ but not $A=3, B=3$ ... Is "empty" one value?

Comment: Have you purposely missed $3$ when taking two items at a time?

Comment: If we were to include *zero* as a possible value, corresponding to how you notated it where the letter just doesn't appear in the first place, it appears that you are possibly reaching for the number of functions from $\{A,B,C\}$ to $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and from some set $X$ to a set $Y$ in general... possibly excluding the function where you map everything to zero for whatever ill-conceived reason.  This can be seen by an elementary application of the rule of product.  Take the number of possibilities for the first, multiply by the number of possibilities for the second, etc...

Comment: The end result is that the number of functions from $X$ to $Y$ is going to be $|Y|^{|X|}$, and in your case $4^3$.  Subtract $1$ from this for your specific case if you are explicitly avoiding the all zero case.

Comment: @Tavish nope it's not meant to be missing. I'm just stupid and missed it as part of the 'manual' processing of writing it out, apologies :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have $x$ variables and want to assign $y$ values to them with $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$, so that is $y^x$ possibilities.

If you want to assign the values $\{0,1,2,3\}$ , with $"0"$ being no value, to the set $\{A,B,C\}$, you have $4^3$ ways of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is that you want to take a subset of your items together with each choice of unique values of the appearing elements in the subset, the the answer should be $4^3$. However, this does not seem match very much with your manual draw.

More generally, if there are $n$ items where each item is associated with a unique value from $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$, then the number of items that you'd like to count would be $(k+1)^n$.

The enumeration of each object would naturally associate with a string of length $n$ whose values of each digit is taken from $\{0,1,\dots,k\}$ where each digit corresponds to an item and the value of the digit corresponds to the unique value of the item. However, if the digit takes a zero value, then interpret it as not appearing in the subset.